# Django with psycopg2 plugin

Tags: python, django

Ive been reading the Django Book and its great so far, unless something doesn't work properly. I have been trying for two days to install the psycogp2 plugin with no luck.

i navigate to the unzipped directory and run setup.py install and it returns "You must have postgresql dev for building a serverside extension or libpq-dev for client side."

I don't know what any of this means, and google returns results tossing a lot of terms I don't really understand.

Ive been trying to learn django for abut a week now plus linux so any help would be great. Thanks

Btw, I have installed postgresql and pgadminIII from installer pack.

I also tried sudo apt-get post.... and some stuff happens...but Im lost.

Comment: You need the PostgreSQL libraries to be able to build the psycopg2 module (`sudo apt-get install postgresql-dev`), but BluesRockAddict's answer is a better solution if you're running Ubuntu or Debian (I assume from apt). Also for Python module installation, always look into using your package manager or look into using `easy_install` or `pip` over downloading the code and building it yourself.

Comment: What Distro Of linux are you running?

Answer (score 13):

I'm using pip as a part of my deployment process, so using apt-get wasn't a viable option for me.

I was able to run

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
```

And remove python-psycopg2 from apt-get.

Then

```
pip install psycopg2
```

worked fine for me.

Answer (score 4):

Try installing using apt-get:

```
sudo apt-get install python-psycopg2
```

Comment: This did something! Im assuming it installed properly, thanks.

Comment: Im using Ubuntu, not really sure of the version. when I try easy install, I get "use sudo apt-get python setuptools", but when i run that its not found

Comment: It should be `sudo apt-get install python-setuptools`

Comment: I needed to install libpq-dev on my ubuntu 12.04 for Django 1.4

Answer (score 3):

I'm working on Xubuntu (12.04) and I have encountered the same error when I wanted to install `django-toolbelt`. I solved this error with the following operations :

- sudo apt-get install python-dev
- sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
- sudo apt-get install python-psycopg2

I hope this informations may be helpful for someone else.

Answer (score -1):

sudo apt-get install python-psycopg2 should work fine since it worked solution for me as well.

Comment: A solution that works for you doesn't imply that it works for others